# Flat Product issue

Tags: magento

as you might guess, when we enable `Flat Catalog Product` option, we can't get product attributes like "name, price etc" from product reports collection. When this option enabled, all attributes are kept in the `catalog_product_flat`. So, I want to make an extension to show most viewed products but no success is because of the above issue.

I tried many ways but nothing happened as follows :

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
  ->addAttributeToSelect(*)
  ->setStoreId($store)
  ->addStoreFilter($store)
  ->addViewsCount();

$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
  ->addAttributeToSelect(*)
  ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'price')) // this will not work is because of the collection
  ->setStoreId($store)
  ->addStoreFilter($store)
  ->addViewsCount();
```

So, do you have any idea to gain mentioned collection?

Comment: left join needed attributes to main collection

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An Inner Join with catalog_product_flat_$storeId should do the trick:

```
    $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
        ->addViewsCount();
    $collection->getSelect()->joinInner(array('e2' => 'catalog_product_flat_'.$storeId), 'e2.entity_id = e.entity_id');

    foreach ($collection as $prod) {
        echo "Name: ".$prod->getName()."\n";
        echo "Price: ".$prod->getPrice()."\n";
        echo "Views: ".$prod->getViews()."\n";
        echo "\n";
    }
```

Can't seem to filter by attribute, though. That gets messed around with the join & addViewsCount() call. It adds the attributes to the select query, but selects * as well.

Comment: Thank you Mike, I tried another way which I got it product attributes.
`$sku = $_product->getData('sku');`  
`$_currentProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $sku);`
 then I get it product attributes from `$_currentProduct`

Comment: Also, we can modify your answer. As you know, the product or catalog flat table name changing based store numbers. If you have more than one store, we should put storeid end of the table name, like :
`catalog_product_flat_$storeId`

Comment: No problems. I figured you could load the products from the original collection, but it's a bit more work for the server. Good point on the store ID. I'll edit my answer for anyone else who comes along.

Comment: Kept getting Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'e.manufacturer' in 'where clause' and wanted to document the error as it traced back to flat product issue. This helped me fix it.